# Find MIN value from multiple columns in a SQL Server table - Return sys.columns ColumnName

Tags: sql-server, date, multiple-columns, min, nullable

Specs: SSMS 2012

Table: 7 columns, one ID column (NOT NULL) & 6 date columns (NULL)

There are thousands of rows in the table:

ID|Date1|Date2|Date3|Date4|Date5|Date6

.

I am trying to find the MIN(DATE) across all 6 Date columns; however, I can't lose track of the Date Column Name (the sys.columns value).  This is needed for reporting which column has the lowest Date.

All of the Date columns can have a NULL value.

I'm open to either creating another column to report the MIN(sys.columns) name or adding a T/F column for each Date Column where 'T' corresponds to the lowest date column.  Obviously NULLs should be avoided when calculating the MIN(DATE).

I was thinking an UNPIVOT would probably be needed.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for reviewing in advance.

Comment: I believe this brut force code would work but it is way to repetitive and time consuming.  I'd prefer something a little more elegant:
'code'
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN (Date1 < Date2 OR Date2 IS NULL)
  AND (Date1 < Date3 OR Date3 IS NULL)
  AND (Date1 < Date4 OR Date4 IS NULL)
  AND (Date1 < Date5 OR Date5 IS NULL)
  AND (Date1 < Date6 OR Date6 IS NULL)
  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS EarliestDAte
FROM Table
where Date1 IS NOT NULL 'code'

Comment: Sounds like the best approach would be to normalize your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider using the VALUES close instead of UNPIVOT. Seems cleaner and "more standard" for me. Check it out.

Table variable (Thanks, Andrew):

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
id INT,
date1 DATE,
date2 DATE,
date3 DATE,
date4 DATE,
date5 DATE,
date6 DATE)

INSERT @dates VALUES
(1,'2014-12-31',NULL,'2014-03-12','2014-04-20','2014-02-10','2014-01-06'),
(2,'2015-11-08','2014-03-18','2014-07-14',NULL,'2014-04-15','2014-01-17'),
(3,'2015-12-13','2014-11-11','2014-09-18','2014-09-01','2014-06-24','2014-01-28'),
(4,'2016-04-24','2014-12-20','2015-04-14','2015-12-27','2015-05-14',NULL),
(5,'2016-08-22','2015-11-16','2016-03-26','2016-08-31','2015-09-25','2015-02-20'),
(6,NULL,'2016-01-13','2016-08-02','2016-10-08',NULL,'2016-05-28'),
(7,'2016-09-22','2016-01-25','2017-03-06','2016-10-19','2017-02-03','2016-06-14'),
(8,'2017-05-21','2017-01-14','2017-11-07','2017-01-22','2017-02-15','2017-10-30'),
(9,'2017-12-15','2017-05-06',NULL,'2017-12-26','2017-11-07','2017-11-01');
```

The query:

```
WITH Unpivoted as (
SELECT [rowId], [date], [colId]
  FROM @dates
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES
              (id, date1, 1)
             ,(id, date2, 2)
             ,(id, date3, 3)
             ,(id, date4, 4)
             ,(id, date5, 5)
             ,(id, date6, 6)
             ) 
          AS T([rowId], [date], [colId])
)
, MinDate as (
SELECT [rowId], MIN([date]) as [date]
  FROM Unpivoted
  GROUP BY [rowId]
  )

  SELECT M.[rowId]
        ,M.[date]
        ,U.[colId]
  FROM [MinDate] as M
  JOIN Unpivoted as U
    ON M.[rowId] = u.[rowId]
   AND M.[date]  = u.[date]
```

Comment: Nice use of CROSS APPLY!  I like this code.  I would have renamed a few things along the way, but that is just nitpicking.  Thank you for the share.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, but it could probably be cleaned up for efficiency if you will run it regularly.

First, here is the table variable I made for this:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
id INT,
date1 DATE,
date2 DATE,
date3 DATE,
date4 DATE,
date5 DATE,
date6 DATE)

INSERT @dates VALUES
(1,'2014-12-31',NULL,'2014-03-12','2014-04-20','2014-02-10','2014-01-06'),
(2,'2015-11-08','2014-03-18','2014-07-14',NULL,'2014-04-15','2014-01-17'),
(3,'2015-12-13','2014-11-11','2014-09-18','2014-09-01','2014-06-24','2014-01-28'),
(4,'2016-04-24','2014-12-20','2015-04-14','2015-12-27','2015-05-14',NULL),
(5,'2016-08-22','2015-11-16','2016-03-26','2016-08-31','2015-09-25','2015-02-20'),
(6,NULL,'2016-01-13','2016-08-02','2016-10-08',NULL,'2016-05-28'),
(7,'2016-09-22','2016-01-25','2017-03-06','2016-10-19','2017-02-03','2016-06-14'),
(8,'2017-05-21','2017-01-14','2017-11-07','2017-01-22','2017-02-15','2017-10-30'),
(9,'2017-12-15','2017-05-06',NULL,'2017-12-26','2017-11-07','2017-11-01')
```

Here is the unpivot query I came up with.

```
SELECT
    col_val,
    date_val
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(date_val,0,charindex(':',date_val,0)) AS col_val,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(date_val,charindex(':',date_val,0)+1,10) AS DATE) AS date_val,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(date_val,charindex(':',date_val,0)+1,10) AS DATE) /*date_val*/) AS rn
    FROM (
        SELECT
            'date1:' + CAST(MIN(date1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date1,
            'date2:' + CAST(MIN(date2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date2,
            'date3:' + CAST(MIN(date3) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date3,
            'date4:' + CAST(MIN(date4) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date4,
            'date5:' + CAST(MIN(date5) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date5,
            'date6:' + CAST(MIN(date6) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date6
        FROM @dates) dates
    UNPIVOT (date_val FOR dates IN (date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, date6)) AS unpvt
    ) tbl
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I received the Error:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

I'm looking into datatypes conversions...

Comment: Can you confirm that the hard-coded date strings include the colon? I removed it and received the error you mention.

Comment: Very long delay :P (shift in priority).  I did the date conversion (CAST), however the returned results aren't grouped by id.  The idea was to get three columns, not two:  [id], [col_val], [date_val].  This code would get applied to each [id].

Answer (score 0):

So this worked.  Probably not the cleanest code, but I added the GROUP BY [id] and did a MIN(date) INNER JOIN:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (
id Varchar(50),
date1 DATE,
date2 DATE,
date3 DATE,
date4 DATE)

INSERT @dates VALUES
(1,'2014-12-31',NULL,'2014-03-12','2014-04-20'),
(2,'2015-11-08','2014-03-18','2014-07-14',NULL),
(3,'2015-12-13','2014-11-11','2014-09-18','2014-09-01'),
(4,'2016-04-24','2014-12-20','2015-04-14','2015-12-27'),
(5,'2016-08-22','2015-11-16','2016-03-26','2016-08-31'),
(6,NULL,'2016-01-13','2016-08-02','2016-10-08'),
(7,'2016-09-22','2016-01-25','2017-03-06','2016-10-19'),
(8,'2017-05-21','2017-01-14','2017-11-07','2017-01-22'),
(9,'2017-12-15','2017-05-06',NULL,'2017-12-26')

SELECT id,col_val,date_val
INTO #TableName
FROM (SELECT id,
    SUBSTRING(date_val,0,charindex(':',date_val,0)) AS col_val,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(date_val,charindex(':',date_val,0)+1,10) AS DATE) AS date_val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(date_val,charindex(':',date_val,0)+1,10) AS DATE) /*date_val*/) AS rn
    FROM (SELECT id,
        'date1:' + CAST(MIN(date1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date1,
        'date2:' + CAST(MIN(date2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date2,
        'date3:' + CAST(MIN(date3) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date3,
        'date4:' + CAST(MIN(date4) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS date4
        FROM @dates
        GROUP BY id
        ) dates
    UNPIVOT (date_val FOR dates IN (date1, date2, date3, date4)) AS unpvt
    ) tbl

Select tbl.*
From #TableName tbl
Inner Join
(Select id,MIN(date_val) min_date_val From #TableName Group By id) tbl1
On tbl1.id=tbl.id
Where tbl1.min_date_val=tbl.date_val
```